# Yarn Workspaces Not Building Local Dependency

Tags: yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I deleted my old question, to provide more info.  I'm using Yarn workspaces (v1.22) on a monorepo with both an Angular app and library. I have the library declared as a dependency of the app.

```
root
   |
   ---projects
         |
         ---lib (components)
         |
         ---app
```

Each project has its associated build scripts. If I run `yarn` on a fresh checkout at the root or `yarn workspace app install`, it installs everything and links to the lib's project folder, but it doesn't perform the build, which is necessary, since my tsconfig paths includes the output of the build `dist/lib`. The last step in the install says "Building Fresh Packages", but it doesn't trigger the build for the lib for some reason.

tsconfig.json (base)

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@fabric/components/*": [
        "./dist/components/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

root package

```
{
  "name": "fabric",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "workspaces": [
    "projects/*"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0 < 16.0.0",
    "yarn": ">= 1.0.0",
    "npm": "Please use Yarn instead of NPM to install dependencies. See: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "components": "yarn workspace @fabric/components",
    "guide-app": "yarn workspace @fabric/guide-app",
    "test": "yarn guide-app test && yarn components test",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/forms": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/localize": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "12.0.2",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "tslib": "2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.0.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "12.0.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.0.2",
    "@schematics/angular": "12.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "14.14.37",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "jest-junit": "12.1.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.4.0",
    "jest-transform-stub": "2.0.0",
    "ng-packagr": "12.0.2",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.2.4"
  }
}
```

lib package

```
{
  "name": "@fabric/components",
  "version": "5.0.2",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0 < 16.0.0",
    "yarn": ">= 1.0.0",
    "npm": "Please use Yarn instead of NPM to install dependencies. See: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ng build components --configuration production",
    "watch": "ng build components --watch",
    "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.0"
  }
}
```

app package

```
{
  "name": "@fabric/guide-app",
  "version": "5.0.1",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0 < 16.0.0",
    "yarn": ">= 1.0.0",
    "npm": "Please use Yarn instead of NPM to install dependencies. See: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fabric/components": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~6.0.0",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "~4.1.3"
  }
}
```

So I guess, first, is my assumption correct, that Yarn *should* be building the dependent package?
And if so, is there something in my config that isn't correct?  If that's not part of yarn's offering, do you have any suggestion to what could be added to support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your folder structure, `workspaces` and `dependencies` are correctly set up. For yarn to invoke your build script you will have to add it to the `postinstall` and/or `prepare` script of your `lib` package:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "...",
    "postinstall": "yarn build"
  }
}
```

When installing the `app` package, it should run the post-install scripts of all its dependencies. Mind however, that this side-effect may not be desired when using `lib` in a different context e.g. as a standalone package.

Note that, when making changes to `lib`, you have to bump its version and that version has to be in the range `app` specifies in its `dependencies`. Only then yarn will re-execute its postinstall script when re-installing the `app`.

---

Apart from that I noticed you used tsconfig's `compilerOptions.paths` to refer to `lib`. There is another way to do this using [typescript references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html). A good starting point is [this article](https://2ality.com/2021/07/simple-monorepos.html#a-better-solution%3A-npm-workspaces-and-typescript-project-references).

Comment: This was helpful but now yarn is building those dependencies in an order that doesn't work based on my workspace dependencies upon one another. I have a mono repo containing packA and packB where packB depends upon packA. So far yarn seems determined to run the postinstall for B before A. So far I've tried declaring the dep using a standard version number "packA": "^1.1.0" and using a workspace: dependency declaration "packA": "workspace:^". Neither have changed the outcome.